# Extracting RSS link with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xpath, rss, screen-scraping, nokogiri

I am using Nokogiri to extract the RSS link from a webpage. However, since some websites have absolute paths and others relative on their HTML, I wanted to make it so that if the website has a relative path it will be made absolute.

Here is my code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'simple-rss'
require 'open-uri'


ARGV.map! { |http| "http://#{http}"}
ARGV.each do |website|
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(website))
rss_path = doc.xpath("//link[@type=\"application/rss+xml\"]").map do |link|
    if link['href'] =~ /^http:\/\/[a-z]*\..*\//i
        puts link['href']
    else
        puts "#{website}#{link['href']}"
    end
end
```

So if I was on command line, I would type something like

```
ruby rss.rb 8gramgorilla.com rubyweekly.com
```

The code works fine for rubyweekly.com which has a relative path for its RSS but 8gramgorilla.com has an absolute path and so I would want it to just be output immediately, not have http://8gramgorilla.com/http://8gramgorilla.com/feed as the output. Basically, what's going on is that the IF statement is being ignored and it goes right away to the else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `if` statement isn’t being ignored, it is evaluating to false. Your regexp is `/^http:\/\/[a-z]*\..*\//i`, so it is looking for `http://` followed by any number of `a-z` (or a `.` since zero `a-z` will also match). But the website url is `http://8gramgorilla.com`, the first character is the digit `8`, which isn’t in the range `a-z`.

The most direct fix to this would be to change your regex to include digits, perhaps something like `/^http:\/\/[\da-z]*\..*\//i` (where `\d` has been added).

You might be able to simplify the regex more, perhaps simply checking to see if the url matches `http://` at the start would be enough.

A more robust solution would be to properly parse the url in question, perhaps using the [Addressable gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/addressable) or the [URI module in Ruby’s standard lib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/index.html).

Comment: Thank you! I tried both adding the \d and just simplifying it to a `http://` match and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for the if, just do:

```
require 'uri'
puts URI.join(website, link['href']).to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

To detect the RSS feed for the New York Times http://www.nytimes.com:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS" href="http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml">
```

I would use the following to extract the `href` value from `application/rss+xml` link tag:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
url = 'http://www.nytimes.com'
resp = HTTParty.get(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(resp.body)
feed = doc.css("link[type='application/rss+xml']").map{|link|link[:href]}.first
```

Which would return the RSS feed value for the site:

```
http://www.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml
```

Note, if the site does *not* have `application/rss+xml` tag, the code will simply return `nil`.